# List always one [JAVA]

Tags: java, list, arraylist, text

I'm trying to read text file in JAVA, retrieve some value and do the query. It should has two data in list, but it only show one.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String st;
List<Object[]> list = null;

try {
    while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String id = st.substring(92, 100); // get from text file
        System.out.println(id);                

        list = commDAO.getDetails(id);  // query
        System.out.println("Total list " + list.size());
    }

    br.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}

logger.printInfo(AAA.class, "**** retrieve list: " + list.size());
```

Output

```
1
Total list 1
2
Total  list 1
retrieve list: 1
```

**getDeails**

```
  public List getDetails(String id) {
          .......
 return em.createQuery(bf.toString())
          .......
     .getResultList();
 }
```

I create another list and add the `list` to TotalList

```
List TotalList = new ArrayList();

list = TotalList.add(id);
```

But get `incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List<Object[]>`

Comment: You're assigning to your `list` variable inside a while loop. Each iteration will overwrite the previous.

Comment: You need to make a change in `getDetails()` method. It this method you may not be adding elements to list but creating new list every time. It would be better if you can show definition of `getDetails()` method.

Comment: Does `getDetails()` always return a list with single element?

Comment: Ok @JohnJoe. If `getDetails()` always return a list with single element then you should return an object from `getDetails()` method not a list.

Comment: @Varun But I'm using List<Object[]> list

Comment: The thing which is not clear from your question is - are you expecting `List<Object[]> list` to have two values in it ? if yes then it looks like you are reading ids from the file and using the ids you are making database calls to populated the list with Database values. So you should be calling `list.add()` method and add the returned values to the `list` object, in order to accumulate all values returned from DB into that list.

Comment: @JohnJoe Then I think you should return `Object[]` from `getDetails()`. Because you want to add `Object[]` in `list`.

Comment: @Varun post edited

Comment: @TarunGupta post edited

Comment: solved.........

Comment: Name of objects should be in camel case as per java convention. Instead of `TotalList` you should use `totalList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does this line do? What is the object `commDAO`?

```
list = commDAO.getDetails(id);
```

It looks like you are overwriting the list object with a completely new list instead of adding an object to the existing list.

Try the following:

```
list.add(commDAO.getDetails(id));
```

or if `commDAO.getDetails(id)` returns a list, the following:

```
list.add(commDAO.getDetails(id).get(0));
```

Comment: So which type does `commDAO.getDetails(id)` return? Based on that you need to choose your solution.

Comment: What is the return type? It would also help if you could state the type of `commDAO` and which package it is in.

Comment: So did you figure it out already? If so, please let us know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If i get it right problem is that you always assign new value to the list instead of adding new one to it.
You have:

```
list = commDAO.getDetails(id);
```

You should have:

```
list.add(commDAO.getDetails(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
List<Object[]> list = new ArrayList<>();

         try {
              while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
                  String id = st.substring(92, 100); // get from text file
                  System.out.println(id);                
                  list.addAll(commDAO.getDetails(id));  // query
                 }
              System.out.println("Total list " + list.size());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
       }
```

**getDetails**

```
 public List<Object[]> getDetails(String id) {
          .......
 return em.createQuery(bf.toString())
          .......
     .getResultList();
 }
```